# How to add key and value in array without foreach, Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I want to make array without foreach loop. This is should be returned:

```
array:4 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "name" => "tag1"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "name" => "tag2"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [
    "name" => "tag3"
  ]
  3 => array:1 [
    "name" => "tag4"
  ]
]
```

I made it to work like this:

```
$tags=[];
$j=0;
foreach($woo->tags as $tag){
    $tags[$j]['name']=$tag;
    $j++;
}
```

But when I have a lot of tags it can be slow in foreach loop. My tags are saved in database in text field like `tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4`
[image]

Is there any other faster way to return this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `array_map`, I haven't actually benchmarked the both but it is one of (if not your only) alternative:

```php
$tags = array_map(function($tag) {
    return ['name' => $tag];
}, $woo->tags);
```

For what it's worth, if you are actually storing so many tags in a singular column that it actually slows PHP down, might be something you need to step back and think about improving.